# C# how to repeat an action

Tags: c#

Basically trying to shorten this:

```
octree[nodeIndices[0]].nodes[nodeIndices[1]]
    .nodes[nodeIndices[2]].nodes[nodeIndices[3]].nodes[nodeIndices[4]]
```

I thought something like this could work, but not sure exactly how:

```
octree[nodeIndices[0]].(Enumerable.Repeat(node[nodeIndices[i]], 4)
```

edit: here's more code

```
OctreeNode[] nodes = octree;
ushort subdivisions = 1;

while (true)
{
    ushort nodeIndex = 0;
    OctreeNode node = nodes[nodeIndex];

    if (node == null)
    {
        node = new OctreeNode();
        node.nodes = new OctreeNode[8];
        nodes = node.nodes;
    }

    subdivisions++;

    if (subdivisions > 4)
        break;
}

// the actual octree variable is unchanged
```

Comment: Unfortunately in C#, there is no `With` like we have in VB.Net.

Comment: Without knowing what an `octree` is, I don't think there's anything we can do for you

Comment: You could write a loop or recursive function for that.

Comment: Not really clear to me is, what the actual problem is. Your first snippet of code looks like a ``OctreeNode getNode( Octree tree, int[] coordinates)`` function to me, where coordinates would be in your example: ``[0,1,2,3,4]``.

Answer (score 4):

```
var result = octree[nodeIndices[0]];

for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
   result = result.node[nodeIndices[i]];

// do something with result;
```

Comment: If I do it that way then I don't think I can set the result, and I hear pointers aren't safe in C#.

Comment: @JimmyChristmas there are no pointers in this answer.

Comment: If I set result it would just be setting that instance of it, not the actual member inside the octree.

Comment: @JimmyChristmas `result.node[nodeIndices[1]]`do the same as `octree[nodeIndices[0]].nodes[nodeIndices[1]]`

Comment: For some reason it isn't for me. Here's more code for what I'm doing. Each `OctreeNode` class has an array of children nodes.

- added the code to main post

Comment: @JimmyChristmas In .NET, classes are reference types (think pointers to instances). So, whenever you create a class, you have a pointer in .NET. But those pointers (aka references) are not as troublesome as they are in C++, as their life time is managed automatically. Were your octree huge and were you frequently changing it, you would sure put some load on the .NET garbage collector, which might be detrimental to run time performance. Yet, this is a performance issue, not a stability issue.